# How do enchantments work?

Tags: the-gold-factory

In the enchantment shop you can buy enchantments for your swords.

What does each enchantment do and how much effect does it have?
Do you lose the enchantments when you acquire a new weapon (and have to start over)?
Can you put multiple enchantments on the same weapon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does each enchantment do and how much effect does it have?

- **Attack** -> Your weapon has more damage
- **Countdown** -> Countdowns are a little bit faster
- **Life** -> Your HP increases each time you attack

> Do you lose the enchantments when you acquire a new weapon (and have to start over)?

When you acquire your new weapon, your enchantment won't be lost

> Can you put multiple enchantments on the same weapon?

Yes

---

Each level of attack gives +7 damage

Each level of life gives +2 hp each time you attack enemy

Countdown has one level only (why not try it?)

Comment: How much effect each enchantment have?

Comment: Each level of attack gives +7 damage, each level of life gives +2 hp each time you attack enemy, countdown has one level only (why not try it?)

Comment: Just wanted the answer to be complete. Can you edit it to include this information?

Comment: Done adding, sorry for the incomplete answer

Comment: Is there a limit to how high the enchantment levels can go (aside from countdown, since it only has one level)?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146699/what-is-the-maximum-enchanting-level